# Trigger Alert on Change Event Only Once If Called Multiple Times In A Few Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an alert that needs to be displayed to the user conditionally after they change their input. The problem I'm coming across is the alert fire rapidly multiple times in a row after they key down quickly. I want the alert to fire only once every few seconds. How can I achieve this?

```
childElem.on('change', function () {
      let currentHeightPaste2k
      let scrnwidth
      setTimeout(function () {
        let actualHeightPaste2k = parseInt($('#' + currenId2c).height()) //Height of DIV
        scrnwidth = $(window).width()
        if (scrnwidth == parseInt(1226)) {
          currentHeightPaste2k = $('#' + currenId2c).get(0).scrollHeight //Content Height of DIV
        } else {
          currentHeightPaste2k = $('#' + currenId2c).get(0).scrollHeight - 1 //Content Height of DIV
        }
        if (actualHeightPaste2k < currentHeightPaste2k) {
          _.throttle(fireError, 300)
          CKEDITOR.instances[currenId2c].execCommand('undo')
        }
      }, 100)
    })

function fireError() {
      toast.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Typing Limit Exceeded',
        text: 'You have inserted more text than the space will allow.',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        confirmButtonClass: 'cancel-btn-class',
      })
    }
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the throttle delay?

Comment: The throttle isn't being triggered at all in this example. It just simply isn't working.

Comment: A *throttle* function means it can only be called so many times with x seconds - ie call once then not again for 300ms.   You might want `_.debounce` which works the other way around - which postpones the action until there have been no events within the timeout.   Your **title** suggests `debounce` (*only once if called multiple times*) but your text contradicts this with (*once every few seconds*) - which is it you want?

Comment: The answer by @Holp is correct. I added a modified version of your code to further clarify the answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m I wouldn't call `debounce` and `throttle` *opposites*... both require the event to fire at least once before the underlying function will be evaluated at all. The main difference is that `debounce` waits until the event stops firing again, while `throttle` just limits the frequency of evaluation.

Comment: @Julian - yes, I as stated: "the other way around" - throttle fires the event at the start, debounce fires it at the end.  (for completeness: throttle fires multiple times while debounce fires once).   I'm not sure why you thought I said "opposite" or what that would even mean other than that described here, in your comment and my previous comment.  The point being that OP has asked for *both* while they are not the same.

Comment: @freedomn-m That was a bad paraphrase on my part, my apologies. Still, I think that "the other way around" is potentially confusing. `throttle` will *also* fire at the end, unless you call it only once.

Comment: @Julian thanks, that's useful additional information:  `throttle` also fires at the end.  I do like your description of the main difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating a new throttled function every time the callback is called. You should try to create the throttled function in a higher scope and use the function returned from `_.throttle` in the callback.

See https://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Comment: Why did you undo my edit? It was meant to clarify your answer. If you don't like it, you can change it again, but just deleting all of the example code seems like throwing out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: If you want to post code do so under your own name by posting a new answer. I'll write my answer and you'll write yours.

Answer (score 0):

`_.throttle` does not *call* the function that you pass to it. Instead, it returns a *new function*. You need to store the new function and call it instead of the old function. The new function ensures that the old function is invoked no more often than the interval that you passed to `_.throttle`. The following code will do what you were trying to achieve (at least as far as throttling is concerned):

```
const fireError = _.throtte(function() {
  toast.fire({
    type: 'error',
    title: 'Typing Limit Exceeded',
    text: 'You have inserted more text than the space will allow.',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    confirmButtonClass: 'cancel-btn-class',
  });
}, 300);

childElem.on('change', function() {
  let currentHeightPaste2k;
  let scrnwidth;
  setTimeout(function() {
    let actualHeightPaste2k = parseInt($('#' + currenId2c).height()); //Height of DIV
    scrnwidth = $(window).width();
    if (scrnwidth == 1226) {
      currentHeightPaste2k = $('#' + currenId2c).get(0).scrollHeight; //Content Height of DIV
    } else {
      currentHeightPaste2k = $('#' + currenId2c).get(0).scrollHeight - 1; //Content Height of DIV
    }
    if (actualHeightPaste2k < currentHeightPaste2k) {
      fireError();
      CKEDITOR.instances[currenId2c].execCommand('undo');
    }
  }, 100);
});
```